# Recieving data from a client

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been searching and researching for two weeks now and am a little confused so Im reaching out to the community.
I am currently paying a company for a service. I have a client that posts data to this service and it gets stored in the database and then gets sent off to another database.
Unfortunately I don't know how the posting service works but Im paying for a ferrari when I need a civic.
I started programming again last December but there is so much more to learn. 
I have my internal site built now and its time to get rid of the ferrari.
If I build a page that posts data to my DB (and skip the middleman) will the automatic posts that the client sends get handled one at a time and return a success code or do I have to build a special api for that?
Example
Page recieves data then inserts the data and returns success code.
Then the next and the next etc.

```
//Page receives the data and checks for token and sets variables for the 
//data fields that corresponds to the columns in the DB.

$token = htmlspecialchars($_GET["token"]);
$data = htmlspecialchars($_GET["data"]);
$data2 = htmlspecialchars($_GET["data2"]);
//if token matches
if ($token = 'xyz'){
    $insert = "INSERT INTO table (datacol,data2col)
                VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data2col=?";
    $stmnt = mysqli->prepare($insert);
    $stmnt->bind_param('s,s', $data, $data2);
    $rslt = $stmnt->execute;
}

if ($rslt){
    print 'success';
} else {
    print 'fail';
)
$stmnt->close();
```

I apologize in advance because I dont even know how the client sends the data except that its to a php page with token and has an example string.

Comment: Then show us the example string!

Comment: I think this `$stmnt->bind_param('s,s', $data, $data2);` should be `$stmnt->bind_param('sss', $data, $data2,$data2);` ?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` shouldn't be used on content going into the database, but coming out from it (when printing). The DB can be a nightmare to normalize and search if you have that going in.

Comment: All this kinda depends on knowing what is coming to this script. You dont seem to know that. The normal development process is to understand the inputs BEFORE attempting to do anything with them!!!!

Comment: You not doing anything with token

Comment: Hi Riggs I do know the data types and data coming in, I dont know the method of posting multiple rows to the one page to replicate it. Can you share a link that explains that? I can't seem to find anything that I can understand.

Comment: Your question  is not straightforward

Comment: hi @RiggsFolly; athe client would post the data to http://somedomain.com/posting.php?token=&data=&data2=   The example code above is just the structure of the page I had envisioned and needs to be refined, just didnt know it would work or not

Comment: error: `$rslt = $stmnt->execute;` should be `$rslt = $stmnt->execute();`

Comment: What you have written is basically an API already. An API does not have to be 20,000 lines of code to deserve the name

Comment: @RiggsFolly So youre saying that if I added security and wrote the code properly, it would accept the data sent and insert into the db and the client would see the success message? Ty, Ill go work on that then, I was just confused with the api terminology etc while trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, creating an API is better than just simple PHP code that allows your client to insert data into your DB. Because Others can use same PHP page to insert data and you will have garbage records.

If you follow the idea of API and you can add basic security to the incoming request and by this way only your client(s) can insert data into your DB. With API you can create multiple endpoints too. So one endpoint allows only one record and other allow batch records so this way you will increase the functionalities and build a better service for your client.

There many other advantages of building an API too.

Comment: Hi Parth; I agree, I will work on the security. I was looking at PHP CRUD but all I need is insert really and I only need to start with one page for now so I can stop paying for a ferrari while I either figure out how to build a working API or pay someone to do it. My thing is I didnt know if my example would work to process multiple data rows as the client sends it or if something else was needed. From what I got from your response is that it will not.Thanks

Comment: If you think my answer was helpful and eligible for a +vote please give a vote Thank you @Semon

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about security could try using a framework like Laravel. It has a lot of security features in place to prevent SQL Injection, input verification and Session hijacking.

It has a bit of a learning curve but once you're through there are some amazing opportunities. A good way to get started is Laravel from Scratch: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017.

Comment: ty. I did download Laravel a few months ago but wasnt comfortable learning it. I will look into it.

Comment: Yeah the initial learning curve can be a bit steep but it's definitely worth it in the long run. Good luck!

Comment: Got through the "how to install" tutorial and I might have to wait till I have the time to learn that lol. For now Im using netbeans, then again in the 90's I learned html with notepad lol